# ASP.NET Web API 2 Model not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am using VS 2013 and ASP.NET Web API **2** for the back-end for an iOS app. Everything was going smoothly until I tried to implement my first POST using Web API 2. I have built a previous API using MVC Web API 1 with no problems implementing POST. Using the [FromBody] attribute should work, but my "request" is always null.  The model is not binding. Can anyone see my error or give me some help?

UsrDTO

```
public class UsrDTO
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public bool isManager { get; set; }
    public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Usr Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/usr")]
public class UsrController : BaseAPIController
{
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]UsrDTO request)
    {
        var ctx = repo.GetContext();
        Usr user = new Usr();
        user.Id = new Guid(userId);
        user.Username = request.email;
        user.FirstName = request.firstName;
        user.MiddleName = request.middleName;
        user.LastName = request.lastName;
        user.Email = request.email;
        user.CompanyId = request.companyId;
        user.IsManager = request.isManager;
        user.IsAdmin = request.isAdmin;
        user.IsActive = true;
        user.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        ctx.Usr.Add(user);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
     } 
}
```

Fiddler Request

```
POST http://localhost:49763/api/usr HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:49763
Content-Length: 230
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
     "firstName" : "test",
     "middleName" : "test",
     "lastName":"test",
     "email": "test@test.com", 
     "companyId" = 1,
     "isManager"=false, 
     "isAdmin"=false
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ugh, typos in my json in the request body. Works now.